# Cordova SplashSreenDelay config.xml parameter assistance

Tags: cordova

I'm writing an iOS app using Cordova and I need a splash screen. I've followed instructions via (http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/config_ref_images.md.html) however the config.xml parameter ...

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="100000" />
```

... is not working. The splash screen loads appropriately but then almost immediately clears. I'd like it to stay loaded for 3 seconds. This is such a simple process that I'm having trouble understanding where I'm going wrong.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have the splashscreen plugin installed? Have you set AutoHideSplashScreen to false?

Comment: My understanding is that I don't nee to have the plugin installed if I configure it via config.xml. AutoHideSplashScreen is immaterial b/c the splash screen displays, it's just not delayed.

Comment: Without the plugin, your splashscreen is just added as the launch image in the ios project which only displays briefly when your app starts up. The plugin allows you to show the splashscreen for a longer period of time while your HTML/CSS/JS assets are being loaded into the webview.

Comment: But the preference tag you see above comes directly from the Cordova document (see link) in which there is no need for the plugin. The page says nothing about needing the plugin.

Comment: I can promise you the plugin reads that preference: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/search?p=2&q=SplashScreenDelay&utf8=%E2%9C%93  while the base cordova does not https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=SplashScreenDelay https://github.com/apache/cordova-lib/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=SplashScreenDelay

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the [splashscreen plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen).

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.splashscreen
```

Also note that for iOS you should set the AutoHideSplashScreen setting to false in config.xml. SplashScreenDelay is used for Android.

Comment: Thanks Connor, I'll give this a shot and report back.